# How to use parentheses in Query Builder in ArcGIS

Tags: sql, arcgis

I would like to make a nested query in a single table by means of parentheses in the Query Builder of ArcGIS.

More specific: I only want to select those Columns which start with **TR-** and in those I want to select those columns that have the attribute **0** (`FieldD`) and **V** and **E** (`FieldB`) *or* **own** (`FieldC`).

[image: Table]

I used the following Syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE:
FieldA LIKE 'TR_%' AND FieldD = 0 AND FieldB in ('V','B') OR FieldC = 'own'
```

the problem is that when I use the Operator *OR* for `fieldC` ArcGIS also considers **KS-**

Thanks

Comment: There are many thousands of ArcGIS Q&As on the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an answer... if not try this...

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE:
FieldA LIKE 'TR_%' AND ((FieldD = 0 AND FieldB in ('V','B')) OR FieldC = 'own')
```